# How to Manage non-JS popups in Selenium?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, dom

I am currently working on testing a site and one of the issues I am running into is working with a non Javascript popup.

I have tried using the Selenium Alert interface.

Sample of what I have done

```
Alert a = WebDriver.switchTo().alert()
alert.accept()
alert.dismiss()
```

This seems to work for Javascript pop up alerts but not for non javascript pop up alerts. Is there any way to deal with pop ups with Selenium that aren't Javascript based?

Comment: It would help to give the URL for the page in question, if possible.

Comment: Sorry its part of an admin thing so I can't give a URL. I'm just wondering if Selenium has a way to deal with pop ups that aren't Javascript based?

Comment: It depends on what kind of popup it is. Is it HTML based? We'd have to see a screenshot and need more info.

Comment: @Jay what kind of popup is it? If it's part of the `html` you can just access it like any other `webelement`

Comment: I believe that it is part of the HTML. So the basic action flow that I am following is clicking on a button and then trying to access a pop up that appears. The popup isn't visible until the button has been clicked and I'm a bit confused about how to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I ran into a pop-up like this, it was a frame that was otherwise "invisible." Open the page with your favorite browser, highlight something in the pop-up, right-click it and choose Inspect Element, then follow its XPath. You may have to switch frames a few times in Selenium to get where you need to be.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this!

Answer (score 0):

If its HTML popup then no specific thing needs to be done, just locate required element normally just like you do for normal web page.

But if its saying element not found then there can be 2 cases:

1. popup is present inside an iframe
2. before this popup you were inside iframe but that pop up is present in defaultContent View.

Depending on case, use these solutions:

For #1 : `driver.switchTo().frame(0);` //Here 0 means first iframe, you can use iframe id also

For #2 : `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();`